# Left join in many tables with where - or condition in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, where-clause

My sample query is below and takes a lot of time to execute as there are many records in OPOS, POS4 tables, like more than 10 million. The or condition in the where clause causes the problem for me.

This is my query:

```
SelecT DISTINCT T0.SaleID,T0.ParentID,T0.CustomerID from OPOS T0 
Left JOIN OCRD C0 ON C0.CustomerID = T0.ParentID --SS / Dist (FOR CUST TYPE) 
LEFT Join POS4 C1 ON T0.SaleID = C1.SaleID AND T0.ParentID = C1.ParentID AND C1.Type = 'C' AND C1.LevelType = 4 -- SS
LEFT Join POS4 C2 ON T0.SaleID = C2.SaleID AND T0.ParentID = C2.ParentID AND C2.Type = 'C' AND C2.LevelType = 2 -- DIST
LEFT Join POS4 C3 ON T0.SaleID = C3.SaleID AND T0.ParentID = C3.ParentID AND C3.Type = 'C' AND C3.LevelType = 3 -- DEALER
LEFT Join POS4 E1 ON T0.SaleID = E1.SaleID AND T0.ParentID = E1.ParentID AND E1.Type = 'E' -- LOGIN EMP USER(CUSTOMER // COMPANY)
LEFT Join POS4 E2 ON T0.SaleID = E2.SaleID AND T0.ParentID = E2.ParentID AND E2.Type = 'E' -- SELECTED EMP USER (COMPANY) 
Where Convert(Date,T0.Date) >= @FromDate AND Convert(Date,T0.Date) <= @ToDate AND C0.Type = @SaleBy AND T0.OrderType IN (12, 13) 
AND E1.TypeID = @LUserID AND E2.TypeID = @SUserID
AND (@SSID = 0 OR C1.TypeID = @SSID) 
AND (@DistributorID = 0 OR C2.TypeID = @DistributorID) 
AND (@DealerID = 0 OR C3.TypeID = @DealerID)
```

Comment: Check actual execution plan - are there any indexes you could add?

Comment: I am guessing the issue is that the performance is terrible. You have a type of catch all query here which can cause serious performance problems. Check out this article on that topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: You're doing a CONVERT on TO.Date. This will prevent any use of an index on that column. Perhaps you should convert FROMDATE and TODATE to the same datatype as TO.Date.

Comment: @Cato we already  added non clustered index on all tables

Comment: @SeanLange not solve my purpose. can you please provide me another solution. it takes same

Comment: @DB101 T0.Date is in Datetime format so we have to convert in date. Is there any problem in query.

Comment: what have you tried?  What happened?  Have you experimented with removing any of the WHERE conditions to see if a particular condition slows things down?  For example it can sometimes help to remove the (@SSID = 0 OR C1.TypeID = @SSID)  from the query, and use two separate queries selected using 'IF' program logic - at the expense of more than one similar query.  You may be able to have some simpler queries for the times where not all selections are being used, and the query optomiser may work better.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your result fields you only need result from T0 and joins are in fact "inner joins" (implied in WHERE). Instead of inner (or left) joining all those tables probably simple EXISTS check would be much better.
What if you rewrite your SQL like this? :

```
SelecT DISTINCT T0.SaleID,T0.ParentID,T0.CustomerID 
from OPOS T0
-- Why should you ever need a conversion of a date field to date?
-- not using Date but Text?
Where T0.[Date] >= @FromDate AND T0.[Date] < @ToDate  
AND EXISTS
(select * from OCRD C0 
  where C0.CustomerID = T0.ParentID and 
  C0.Type = @SaleBy AND T0.OrderType IN (12, 13)) --SS / Dist (FOR CUST TYPE)
AND EXISTS
(select * from POS4 E1 
  where T0.SaleID = E1.SaleID
  AND T0.ParentID = E1.ParentID 
  AND E1.Type = 'E'
  AND E1.TypeID = @LUserID) -- LOGIN EMP USER(CUSTOMER // COMPANY) 
AND EXISTS
(Select * from POS4 E2 
 where T0.SaleID = E2.SaleID 
   AND T0.ParentID = E2.ParentID 
   AND E2.Type = 'E'
   AND E2.TypeID = @SUserID) 
) -- SELECTED EMP USER (COMPANY) 

AND (@SSID = 0 OR 
 EXISTS
 (select * from POS4 C1 
  where T0.SaleID = C1.SaleID AND 
        T0.ParentID = C1.ParentID AND 
        C1.Type = 'C' AND 
        C1.LevelType = 4 AND
        C1.TypeID = @SSID)
) --SS
AND (@DistributorID = 0 OR 
  EXISTS
  ( select * from POS4 C2 
     where T0.SaleID = C2.SaleID 
       AND T0.ParentID = C2.ParentID 
       AND C2.Type = 'C' 
       AND C2.LevelType = 2 
       AND C2.TypeID = @DistributorID)
  )  -- DIST
AND (@DealerID = 0 OR 
      EXISTS
      (select * from POS4 C3 
       where T0.SaleID = C3.SaleID 
         AND T0.ParentID = C3.ParentID 
         AND C3.Type = 'C' 
         AND C3.LevelType = 3 
         AND C3.TypeID = @DealerID)
); -- DEALER
```

EDIT: In code edited the where part where it checks for date.

```
Where T0.[Date] >= @FromDate AND T0.[Date] < @ToDate
```

This would benefit from an index on [Date]. Also note that it uses >= and < as operators (not <= @ToDate). That is the correct way of doing a datetime range query in MS SQL server (a datetime value has 3ms sensitivity). You supply your @FromDate and @ToDate values in such a way that @FromDate is inclusive of the first DateTime you want to have and @ToDate is the min DateTime that you want to exclude.

Converting to date, you want to check only on dates and say do want to return all the records that are in June 2018 as an example. Then your @FromDate would be "20180601" (2018 June 1st 00:00:00 when implicitly converted to Datetime), and @toDate would be "20180701" (2018 July 1st 00:00:00 converted implicitly). That precisely means all records in June 2018. 
IOW it would be:

```
t0.[Date] >= '20180601' and 
t0.[Date] <  '20180701'
```

As you have done it corresponds to:

```
Convert(date, t0.[Date]) >= '20180601' and 
Convert(date, t0.[Date]) <= '20180630'
```

but there is no need to convert Datetime to date and precisely returns the data on requested dates.

Comment: you missed some filtoration EXISTS (select * from POS4 S1 where T0.SaleID = S1.SaleID AND T0.ParentID = S1.ParentID AND S1.Type = 'A' AND S1.TypeID = @RegionID) -- REGION. Still is take many times.

Comment: @pratik1020, no I didn't miss anything. Those are not in the query you supplied. Maybe you should check your indexes,

Comment: @pratik1020, you have a date (or datetime) in your query. Did you try recompiling your query and thus refreshing query plan? "Select .... option(recompile)".

Comment: @pratik1020, also are you sure you have an index with key convert(date, [date]) ? Why would you do such a conversion in first place is also questionable.

Comment: I just saw "T0.Date is in Datetime format so we have to convert in date.". No you don't have to convert to a Date. I will edit my reply to show how.

Comment: And one more comment, please do not reply back after days. The sooner the better.